# Getting -[CFURL retain] crash?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am getting below crash on console

-[CFURL retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x691edc0

I am sending one videourl to another view to play video in MPMovieplayer. any idea.. Thanks

Comment: Do post more code of how you're handling your CFURL object.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is high-level. At a similarly high level: Run with Zombies enabled in Instruments. When you reproduce the error, find the zombie object, and review its reference count history/actions to determine where the imbalance was introduced.